# How to define mathematical objects from scratch?

Tags: soft-question, set-theory, first-order-logic, foundations

Are there any "[Zermelo-type theories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo_set_theory#The_axioms_of_Zermelo_set_theory)" for some other type of mathematical objects except for sets? I.e., axiomatic systems for mathematical objects formalized for first-order logic using a language consisting of one or more non logical symbols (corresponding to $\in$)?

How to think about those systems, do they define the objects or the non logical symbols or both? Or are such systems merely statutes, rules for working with the objects and symbols? Could a system of this kind ever be categorical?

Edit: as the question is formulated Peano axioms for natural numbers and Tarski axioms for geometry are examples. Among others! But I thought I was asking for something else. But I think I learned something anyway, both from formulating the question and from reading the comments.

Comment: Avoid such titles. If one searches for "scratch" in the web, one would not get a hit from this question.

Comment: Here are many examples of first-order theories: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_first-order_theories

Comment: @Arthur: As far as I know, Hilbert's axioms are not first order, but Tarski's are.

Comment: @Arthur - I do not thin so; see [Hilbert's axioms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert's_axioms) : it a three-sorted anguage (points, lines, planes) but the **Axiom of line completeness** is stated in terms of "a system of points, straight lines, and planes". For an elementary axiomatization, see [Tarski's axioms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_axioms).

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you're looking for something like [map theory](http://www.diku.dk/~grue/papers/Grue08/Grue08.pdf), which is an attempt to provide a general foundation for mathematics where the fundamental objects are functions rather than sets?

Comment: I will look at it. Has it something to do with a computer programming language called ML, Meta Language?

Comment: @Lehs: Yes, quite a bit. (I can't answer detailed questions about it, though -- I once tried to read an earlier version of the system, but it seems to have changed significantly since that one).